# angular4 change detection update all components inside ngfor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have 2 components:

- x-list-component and xcomponent.
- x-list-component uses the *ngfor='let VAR of array' directive to create a list of xcomponent and pasts VAR as an input to xcomponent.

  ```
    <xcomponent [VAR]='VAR'></xcomponent>
  ```

xcomponent uses interpolation in the template to render the passed VAR inside a div.
{{VAR.args}}

Everything is ok but when changedetection occurs inside one instance of xcomponent the view is rerendered and the new value of VAR.args appears by all the others xcomponents instead of only on the xcomponent which modified his VAR.args.

so I want to know how I can only updates the view of the xcomponent which emitted the change detection and keep the state of others xcomponents unchanged.

```
//list component and his template
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-kameroke-list',
  templateUrl: './kameroke-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kameroke-list.component.css']
})
export class KamerokeListComponent implements OnInit {
  lyrics=[{"first":"paroles","second":"paroles2","third":"paroles3","id":"test"},
  {"first":"lyrics","second":"lyrics2","third":"lyrics3","id":"secondTest"}
  ];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}


<!--template for list-component-->
    <app-kameroke *ngFor="let lyric of lyrics"  [first]="lyric.first" [second]="lyric.second" [third]="lyric.third"></app-kameroke>

<!--attribuer un id dynamiquement : [attr.id]="lyric.id"-->





//kamerokeComponent and his template
import { Component, OnInit , Input ,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-kameroke',
  templateUrl: './kameroke.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kameroke.component.css']
})
export class KamerokeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() url:string;
  @Input() private first:string;
  @Input() private second:string;
  @Input() private third:string;
  masked:boolean=true;
  playing:boolean=false;

  widget :any;
  lyrics:object;

  constructor(private ref:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //all this event in insertFrame
    this.lyrics={
      1:"ca marche",
      2:"ca cartonne",
      3:"c le feu",
      4:"testons voir"
    };
    this.widget=window['SC'].Widget(document.getElementById("test"));
    this.widget.bind(window['SC'].Widget.Events.PLAY,()=>{this.playing=true});
    this.widget.bind(window['SC'].Widget.Events.PAUSE,()=>{this.playing=false});
    this.widget.bind(window['SC'].Widget.Events.FINISH,()=>{this.playing=false});
    this.widget.bind(window['SC'].Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS,()=>{
     this.widget.getPosition(
                (time)=>{
          //TODO set les variables first second and third
          if(this.lyrics){
            let timing=Math.ceil(time/1000);
            //console.log(this.lyrics[timing]);
            if(this.lyrics[timing]){
              console.log(timing);
              this.first=this.lyrics[timing];
              this.second=this.lyrics[timing];
              this.third=this.lyrics[timing];
              this.ref.detectChanges();
              }
            }
          }
                );
    });
    

  }
  hide(){
    this.masked=false;   
  }
}

<!--kamerokeComponent template-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm soundcloudCol">
        <iframe (load)="hide()" id="test" allow="autoplay" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"
        src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://soundcloud.com/maahlox/la-vie-cest-la-bastonde&amp;{ ADD YOUR PARAMETERS HERE }">
        </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div  class="row lyrics" [hidden]="masked" >
    <div class="col-sm">
        <br><br>
        <p class="first">{{first}}</p>
        <p class="second">{{second}}</p>
        <p class="second">{{third}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please include your code in the question

Comment: i added the code dear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because on your `ngOnInit` you are getting the element by id from the hard-coded value `"test"`. Then for all your `kamerokeComponent` components there will be only one widget element. So when you change that all of your `kamerokeComponent` values will get changed. I suggest to pass the `id` of the element as well.

```html
// template for list-component
<app-kameroke *ngFor="let lyric of lyrics"  [first]="lyric.first"
  [second]="lyric.second" [third]="lyric.third" [id]="lyric.id"></app-kameroke>
```

```js
//kamerokeComponent
import { Component, OnInit , Input ,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-kameroke',
   templateUrl: './kameroke.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./kameroke.component.css']
})
export class KamerokeComponent {
   @Input() url:string;
   @Input() private first:string;
   @Input() private second:string;
   @Input() private third:string;
   @Input() private id:string;
   masked:boolean=true;
   playing:boolean=false;

   widget :any;
   lyrics:object;

   constructor(private ref:ChangeDetectorRef) {
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      //all this event in insertFrame
      this.lyrics={
         1:"ca marche",
         2:"ca cartonne",
         3:"c le feu",
         4:"testons voir"
      };
      this.widget=window['SC'].Widget(document.getElementById(this.id));
      this.widget.bind(window['SC'].Widget.Events.PLAY,()=>{this.playing=true});
      this.widget.bind(window['SC'].Widget.Events.PAUSE,()=>{this.playing=false});
      this.widget.bind(window['SC'].Widget.Events.FINISH,()=>{this.playing=false});
      this.widget.bind(window['SC'].Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS,()=>{
      this.widget.getPosition((time)=>{
         //TODO set les variables first second and third
         if(this.lyrics){
            let timing=Math.ceil(time/1000);
            //console.log(this.lyrics[timing]);
            if(this.lyrics[timing]){
              console.log(timing);
              this.first=this.lyrics[timing];
              this.second=this.lyrics[timing];
              this.third=this.lyrics[timing];
              this.ref.detectChanges();
           }
        }
      });
   });
  }
   hide(){
      this.masked=false;   
   }
}
```

Comment: thks i already did it but faced another problem:when i tried to get the iframe by id with this.id i dont know why but the iframe is not already in the DOM.i added a console.log(document.getElementById(this.id) inside the ngOnInit() method and it prints null in the console

Comment: Did you change the iframe's id `[id]="id"` like this?

Comment: And also try logging the `this.id` as well

Comment: yes i did .i also tried [attr.id]={{id}} same result

Comment: console.log(this.id) prints the right values for each iframe

Comment: This is because angular `ngOnInit` runs before your view loads. Add your code inside `ngAfterViewInit`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: oh dearrrrr thks so muchh .it worked very welll (y).